# How to design an API for different kinds of users?

Tags: c#, java, c, api, api-design

I'm designing a new API for my product.

The code is to be written in C, C# and Java and my goal is to create an API with different levels of control for different kinds of users.

The following is an example of an API which includes all levels of control:

```
class MyAPI
{
    // This method shoudl be available for all users
    public int level_1_function(int x, int y) {return 0;}

    // This method should be available for users of level 2 and above
    public int level_2_function(String s, int x) { return 0; }

    // This metho should be available for users of level 3 and above
    public String level_3_function(String s, int y) { return "Result"; }
}
```

The simplest approach is to use pre-processor directives `#ifdef LEVEL_1` and compile  the code 3 times, each time with different pre-processor directive. This will result in 3 different binaries for the different kinds of users.

I want to avoid creating 3 binaries. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't each user set use different classes? Then you can encapsulate the semantics better? In other words why only one API? Why not provide 3 APIs?

Comment: Create three interfaces and have a function that returns the appropriate "level" of interface?  This does have precedence in, say, COM; an object can present any number of interfaces, and you query for the interface you want.

Comment: Why don't you check the *"level"* of the user in a single method and return appropriate result?

Comment: yeah. let all user access all the methods and throw an error if they are not authorized

Comment: @PreetSangha: 3 APIs means 3 different binaries. That is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @noti: You have three separate APIs already; you're just not *explicitly* separating them.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat: If a user is unauthorized to use a certain function I don't want him even to know it exists.

Comment: @cHao: Yes I know. But by not explicitly separating them, I get code which is easier to maintain, don't I?

Comment: @cHao - actually that's not always true. Complexity doesn't come from the number of parts, rather it comes from combinatorial number of interactions. Anyway in your case - if you want one binary and you want to hide the other functions then a #define is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @noti: Hardly.  You have one class masquerading as three.  Any time one of the three fake classes changes, that means changing the one real class.  What happens if those changes start interfering with each other?  Better to have an underlying type present one clear set of universal operations, IMO, and then split the level-specific functionality off into decorators (that can then be changed without changing the main class and potentially breaking the other decorators).

Comment: > "If a user is unauthorized to use a certain function I don't want him even to know it exists." ... If you ship a binary that contains the code at all, the user can know it exists, and there's not really anything you can do to prevent him from knowing - only not shipping it. Using compile time guards and 3 separate binaries is the correct approach if you need this.

Comment: what happens when you upgrade a user to lets say from level 1 to level2. You ship a new assembly?

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat: My preferred approach would be to only ship a new credential file of some sort.

Comment: If I go with the 3 binary approach, I still have a problem if user with level 1 api gets (in some way) the api with level 2. So this introduces a much difficult problem. This may become a licensing problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyUser
{
    int level = 0;
    setUserLevel(int newLevel) {
        level = newLevel
    }
}

class MyAPI
{
    // This method shoudl be available for all users
    public int level_1_function(int x, int y) { return 0;}

    // This method should be available for users of level 2 and above
    public int level_2_function(String s, int x) { if (level < 2) return -1; else return 0; }

    // This metho should be available for users of level 3 and above
    public String level_3_function(String s, int y) { if (level < 3) return "Invalid access" else return "Result"; }
}
```

Comment: Very important question. Who is using this API? Are they literally writing code to use this api? Unless you specifically say "This code handles different user levels" tell the person who uses your api that THEY need to handle user access levels.